# Sort a string column by datetime in a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to sort a `DataTable` on a `string` column by `DateTime`.

For various reasons, the column must be left as a `string` data type. I know I can copy the data out into another table, convert that column to a `DateTime` column, sort on that and copy it back but I'm wondering if there's a neater way.

I've tried the basics of `DefaultView` and `LINQ` to no prevail.

Comment: What's the format of the string? Is it `dd/MM/yyyy` or something else?

Comment: no definite format, almost anything DateTime.Parse can take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Add while create DataTable

```
    table.Columns.Add("dateValue", typeof(DateTime?));

    var orderedRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      orderby  row.Field<DateTime>("Date")
                      select row; 
    DataTable tblOrdered = orderedRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

**(Or)**

```
 var orderedRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      let date = DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("Date"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                      orderby date 
                      select row;
```

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon a method right after I posted.

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                         orderby DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>(propertyName)) ascending
                                         select row;
dataTable = query.AsDataView().ToTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort dates as a string if you use the format `YYYYMMDD`

Comment: my values are in strings, potentially even something like Jun-99, Jun-00. Basically need to cast them to dates, sort as dates, output them as strings all in one go.

Comment: Ok. Parse them in C# using DateTime.ParseExact by specifying your format and you should be fine after converting to DateTime

Comment: Not exactly.. This will order by month then day then year as an example `"01012001", "01012002", "01022001"` will be ordered as `01012001, 01012002, 01022001`. To properly order this I would choose the format `yyyyMMdd`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<DataRow> rows = new List<DataRow>();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        rows.Sort((r1,r2)=>DateTime.Parse((string)r1["columnname"]).CompareTo(DateTime.Parse((string)r2["columnname"])));
        var clone = table.Clone();
        rows.ForEach(r => clone.Rows.Add(r.ItemArray));
        return clone;
```