# How do I sort DataTable by ascending dates?

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, datatable

My c# code downloads stock quotes into a DataTable object. The data comes as descending dates on the first column. I would like to sort this table as ascending dates. I've tried the following:

```
table.DefaultView.Sort = "Date";
```

sorts the table as if it were of string type, e.g.: "1/1/1994", "1/1/1995", "1/1/1996" instead of the desired "1/1/1994", "1/2/1994", "1/3/1994".

Now, the following raises InvalidCastException.

```
var newTable = table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date")).CopyToDataTable();
```

Note: This sorting happens in a method that returns a DataTable object.

[UPDATE]
this is how I create and fill the table from a List where each entry is formatted as e.g.: "1/1/1994,21.01,22,21,21.01,23131,21.01"

```
        List<string> list = Downloaders.DownloadContentToList(symbol);

        DataTable table = new DataTable(symbol);
        table.Columns.Add("Date");
        table.Columns.Add("Open");
        table.Columns.Add("High");
        table.Columns.Add("Low");
        table.Columns.Add("Close");
        table.Columns.Add("Volume");
        table.Columns.Add("Adj Close");

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] cols = list[i].Split(',');

            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(cols[0]);
            double open = Convert.ToDouble(cols[1]);
            double high = Convert.ToDouble(cols[2]);
            double low = Convert.ToDouble(cols[3]);
            double close = Convert.ToDouble(cols[4]);
            double volume = Convert.ToDouble(cols[5]);
            double adjClose = Convert.ToDouble(cols[6]);
            table.Rows.Add(date, open, high, low, close, volume, adjClose);
        }
```

Comment: Has the column Date a DateTime type ? If it has the string datatype then it is expected to get that exception

Comment: We need to take a look at the part of the code where you create an fill your `DataTable` in order to analyse why you can't sort by date. As @Steve stated, if the DataType of the column isn't set to date, the sorting algorithm will assume you want to sort by whatever is the correct sort order for the DataType of the column (very likely string).

Comment: I updated the question with the information about the DataTable, thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

When Creating Your Table You Should add "date" column as :

```
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
```

then :

```
table.DefaultView.Sort = "Date desc";
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create the datatable you have to specify that it is a date even if it is in string format:

```
table.Columns.Add("dateValue", typeof(DateTime?));

    var orderedRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      orderby  row.Field<DateTime>("Date")
                      select row; 
    DataTable tblOrdered = orderedRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

or:

```
var orderedRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      let date = DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("Date"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                      orderby date 
                      select row;
```

[This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249988/sort-a-string-column-by-datetime-in-a-datatable) but I think the answer also applies to you.

Comment: "table.Columns.Add("dateValue", typeof(DateTime?))" gives me "DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>", correct is "table.Columns.Add("dateValue", typeof(DateTime))"

Answer (score 1):

The "Date" column should be added as so:

```
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
```

rather than

```
table.Columns.Add("Date");
```